# Leaflet geojson layer feature group mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

By default when you hover over a feature group in leaflet the mouse pointer will change to a 'pointer'.  I was wondering if there was an easy way to override this default behavior.  I would like to not change the mouse pointer as in our use case, the feature group is not 'clickable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you create the layer you can pass in 'clickable:false' as an option to disable clickability type styling.

Answer (score 3):

The `clickable:false` answer does not work. Instead, set the path options style of the GeoJSON while creating it. The property to set is `interactive:false`, like so:

```
let yourGeoJSONLayer = L.geoJSON(yourGeoJSON, {style:{interactive:false}});
yourGeoJSONLayer.addTo(map);
```

`L.geoJSON` takes a [GeoJSON options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#geojson-option) object, of which the style value is a [Path options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#path-option) object. This inherits options from `InteractiveLayer`, which has a default setting of `interactive` to `true`.